# como limitar el envio de emails en django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Buenas:

En la web que estoy desarrollando, envia un email al propietario del producto cada vez que otro usuario lo mete en favorito y he encontrado que si empiezas a clicar muchas veces no cesará de enviar emails a esa persona con el mismo mensaje, entonces quiero saber si hay alguna manera de controlar eso y que no repita emails al menos en un periodo de tiempo Cita en bloque

```
def dar_like(request):
    producto = Producto.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('producto'))
    perfil = Perfil.objects.get(usuario = request.user)
    notificacion = Notificacion.objects.get(perfil=producto.perfil)
    data = {'mensaje':'completado'}
    if Like.objects.filter(producto=producto,perfil=perfil).exists():
        like = Like.objects.get(producto=producto)
        like.perfil.remove(perfil)
        like.save()
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        like = Like.objects.get(producto=producto)
        like.perfil.add(perfil)
        like.save()
        if notificacion.nuevo_seguidor == True:
            html = render_to_string('intranet/emails/like_producto.html',{'producto':producto,'perfil':perfil})
            msg = EmailMessage('Like a un producto tuyo', html, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=[producto.perfil.usuario.email])
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send(fail_silently=False)
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

este es el código, como puedes comprobar cada vez que entre en la condición del if mandará un correo sin ningún control

Mi modelo es este

```
class Like(models.Model):
    perfil = models.ManyToManyField(Perfil, related_name='likes')
    producto = models.OneToOneField(Producto)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que ***persistir*** el momento del envío del like (normalmente en BD) y comparar cada nuevo like para ver si ha transcurrido el periodo de tiempo antes de enviar el mensaje.

Mejor opción sería contar los likes durante el periodo y enviar un mensaje con los likes producidos en x horas, diarios, semanales, etc. dándole la opción al propietario del producto de seleccionar el periodo. Además, si guardas cada like con su marca de tiempo, puedes obtener estadísticas más completas como las horas del día y días en que un producto obtiene más likes, es un poco depende de lo que quieras ofrecer.

Comment: el problema es que en mi modelo tengo esto 

class Like(models.Model):
    perfil = models.ManyToManyField(Perfil, related_name='likes')
    producto = models.OneToOneField(Producto)

y la marca de tiempo la deberia de tener perfil, pero eso genera una segunda tabla y no sé como modificarla para añadirle otro campo más

Comment: Sólo te daba una idea, la respuesta puede ser muy amplia. Añade la nueva información a la propia pregunta (puedes editarla), por ejemplo motor de BD, campos y relaciones de las tablas implicadas, etc. Si tu caso no se puede reproducir es más difícil que se te de una solución.

Comment: La solución que he pensado, es crear una cola de emails y un cron que controle los envios de emails. Gracias por tu ayuda